# How many 1s in the base 10 list of numbers from 1 to trillion?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Also how many doublets of 1s? For example the number 311 has 1 doublets of 1s, and 2111 has two doublets of 1s. Also, if you instead concatenated the consecutive numbers from 1 to a trillion, how many doublets of 1s in that case?(I mean for example, if you concatenate the consecutive numbers 1,151 and 1,152 you have an extra doublet from the last 1 in 1,151 and the first 1 in 1,152. )

Answer (score 1):

In listing all the numbers from $0$ to $10^{12}-1$ every tenth number will have a $1$ in the first place.  That is $10^{11}$ times.  That's $10^11$.  For all of the other places, each digit will appear in the $k$th place exactly $1/10$ of the time.  SO that will be a $1$ appears in the $k$th place $10^{11}$.  Add those up it is $12*10^{11}$ ones.  Going from $1$ to $10^{12}$ removes the number $0$ and adds the number $1,000,000,000,000$.  So that is $1$ more $1$.

So there are $12*10^{11}+1$ ones.